# Do asynchronous calls create a separate thread and do they free up CPU cycles?

Tags: asynchronous, async-await

From what I've been taught, async calls do 2 things:

1. Create a new thread for the work that needs to be done. Unless you await that call, the thread for that async call will run separately; your parent thread is free to move on to the next statement unless your async call was awaited.
2. Async calls free up CPU resources. If you make an async call which then waits for a network response (such as making a call to an HTTP API), async calls "know" to not use up CPU cycles while waiting and allow other threads to use the remaining cycles until a response is received.

Ive seen a lot of answers stating that async calls do not create another thread. I know for a fact that's not true. If I don't await an async call, I KNOW that the execution will move to the next statement and even let the parent thread finish regardless of whether or not the async call finished.

Why is there so much confusion around this? There are a lot of stack overflow answers that are accepted that state async calls do not create another thread.

Is my understanding of async calls incorrect? Do they create a new thread? Do they free up CPU cycles instead of wasting CPU cycles while waiting?

Comment: All CPU based calls (or network callbacks) run on threads from the thread pool that could grow on demand. Once you deplete the pool blocking will occur. In your observation the next statement might not run until a/the thread is available again.

Comment: A blocking call, like waiting for network input, always frees up CPU resources, whether called asynchronously or not.  If you call it synchronously, your thread blocks, but it consumes no CPU while doing so; other threads can be run while you're waiting.  So it's really just a matter of whether the calling thread has got something else useful to do while waiting for the I/O.  If anything, async calls use slightly more CPU due to the additional context switching overhead.

Comment: "I know for a fact that's not true." -- [citation needed].

Answer (score 1):

> *"Ive seen a lot of answers stating that async calls do not create another thread"* -

Indeed, It doesn't create another thread, Because The main point of async operation is use less thread as possible (Even a single thread could do the job!).

In threated environment, Create a separate execution (Task) is done by using A threadpool or thread per connection. This is called multithreaded blocking I/O, Not async operation.

> *"Is my understanding of async calls incorrect?"* -

Yes

> *"Do they create a new thread?"* -

No

> *"Do they free up CPU cycles instead of wasting CPU cycles while waiting?"*

Async mean, Not to wait, They execute you code asynchronously, So they don't block on any I/O, And use CPU cycles very efficiently (For I/O intensive Operation).